# How to make sympy.plotting.plot3d to ignore undefined points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols("x y z")
eq= Eq(x**2+y**2+z**2-16,0)
s=solve(eq,z)
plotting.plot3d(*s)
```

The above code produces the following output.

[image]

How can I remove all the zeros plotted where `z` coordinate value is not defined?

In my actual program, `s` is a list of solutions obtained from `sympy.solve` so manually specifying parametric surface is not an option.

Comment: What about filtering out the 0s before plotting `z = filter(None, z)` ?

Comment: @alec `z` is not a list but a sympy expression. I do not understand how this will work. Will it?

Comment: It may not be possible. For every point outside the sphere the square root returns an imaginary number, whose real part is 0. You could hack those values to be np.nan instead, but when `ax.plot_surface` is called, you get a warning and an empty plot. I found a [ticket](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12395) that says plot_surface doesn't support nan values. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109035/2243104) claims otherwise, and I can replicate its result despite the warning, but I don't understand why in your plot the moment one nan is present, it goes blank.

Comment: So far I'm editing the actual sympy source files and if this works one could further try to see if you can trick sympy pass those nan values with a piecewise function ofrsomething, without editing the source code. And it's starting to feel like the effort isn't worth it.